# Generating of table of list of values of function is stucked while the function itself works fine

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following strange situation.

I generate a table

```
Table1[a_,b_]:=Table[{a, b,0.01*i,function[a,b,0.01*i]},{i,0,20,1}]
```

Here `function[a,b,0.01*i]` involves complicated numeric integration. Then I choose particular values of parameters a and b and wait for the table to be generated. It turns out that it's stuck.

However, when I try to display in separate strings all possible values of function for all particular i (i.e., just call the function with the given a, b, i), it turns out that it works perfectly (and just requires some amount of time), with finite total time of evaluation.

What can be a reason for this issue?

Comment: Could be that `Table` effectively uses `Block`...but hard to say without knowing `function`. -- Or put another way, problems with code usually require the code for meaningful answers.

Comment: @MichaelE2: the code is long and complicated, involving external files, and unfortunately it is very inconvenient to paste it here. Could you please tell me how to check whether the table uses Block?

Comment: `Table` does use `Block` ("effectively" according to the docs).  Check if the code `function` calls uses a global variable `i`.  It could also be how you call `Table[a, b]`.  Maybe you should use the pattern check `?NumericQ` on the arguments `a_` and `b_`.  Unhappy families are unhappy in their own way, as Tolstoy said.  It's often true of code, too.